# SED to replace special pattern in script files

Tags: sed

I have PHP scripts that have code that I want to change from:

```
Function1_show();Function2_show();
```

And I want the file to be changed to this:

```
call_my_func("Function1");
call_my_func("Function2");
```

I don't use regex very often so I am not sure how to key on the "_show();" on the end of each function. SED seems like the best function for this but any help is appreciated.

Comment: What are the rules for the names `Function1`, `Function2`? are they always composed of alphanumeric characters only?

Comment: What are the names of those functions, do they always start with "Function_"? Is there always an underscore? Do they all end in "_show()"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed -i 's/\([A-Za-z0-9_]*\)_show();/call_my_func("\1");/g' *.php
```

The `-i` option sell `sed` to update the *.php files in-place.

This searches for alphanumeric text (including underscores) followed by `_show();` and captures that text.

This whole string gets replaced by `call_my_func("`, the captured text, and `");`.

This gets repeated if the match text occurs more than once because of the modifier `g`.

It would have been possible to use `[a-z0-9_]` without `A-Z` by using the `i` modifier, but then it would also match `Function_SHOW();` which is probably not what is desired.

Comment: That is perfect.  Thanks for the help!